# Pickle is able to serialize code object in .ipynb, but fails to do it in .py. Why so?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Trying to make my first steps to the marvelous world of Python programming, I stumbled on the very beginning.

I'm trying to implement a virtual machine for Python bytecode on Python (for educational purposes). So, separating the process of making the bytecode and running it — kind of seems like a good idea. I would like to serialize code objects into files before deserializing and running it in a separated script.

Here is how the code of serializer looks like:

```
import pickle

code_obj = compile("print('Hi!')", "<string>", "exec", dont_inherit=True)
ps = pickle.dumps(code_obj)
with open(r"./hi.dump", "wb") as f_dump:
    f_dump.write(ps)
```

And here is how it crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Syncthing/tragicon/_x/Python/pyro/dumper.py", line 4, in <module>
    ps = pickle.dumps(code_obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'code' object
```

Well, maybe it should be just taken as a premise that code objects are not suitable for `pickle.dumps`. Or maybe it's not, cause there's no problem running exactly the same code in Jupiter Notebook:

```
import pickle

code_obj = compile("print('Hi!')", "<string>", "exec", dont_inherit=True)
ps = pickle.dumps(code_obj)
with open(r"./hi.dump", "wb") as f_dump:
    f_dump.write(ps)
ps
```

Output:

```
b'\x80\x04\x95u\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x12ipykernel.codeutil\x94\x8c\tcode_ctor\x94\x93\x94(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x02K@C\x0ce\x00d\x00\x83\x01\x01\x00d\x01S\x00\x94\x8c\x03Hi!\x94N\x86\x94\x8c\x05print\x94\x85\x94)\x8c\x08<string>\x94\x8c\x08<module>\x94K\x01C\x00\x94))t\x94R\x94.'
```

I would easily take that it's impossible to serialize code objects with pickle, but this contradiction in behavior leaves me perplexed.

Or maybe there's a batter way to do the serialization.

I'd be happy to get some advice on this one.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), it seems that code objects are not Pickleable.  (See "What can be pickled and unpickled"). I have no idea what loophole Jupiter adds, and I'm definitely following this thread.

Comment: I don't know what Jupyter does either, but https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle is designed to be able to pickle code objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the answer is found.

Inquiry revealed, that Jupiter Notebook attaches module `ipyparallel.serialize.codeutil` to its runtime (`ipykernel.codeutil` in some versions). And the only thing this module does is allowing you to pickle code objects.

Thus, to make my initial code work, I should've put `import ipyparallel.serialize.codeutil` on the top of my script (`pip install ipyparallel` might also be required).